# List c# ayuda distribucion de listas

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

Soy nuevo en el desarrollo  de lista , tengo una consulta:
suponiendo que tengo una lista con campos id,nombre, almacen, codigo.
y el codigo se repite por ejemp 001,002,003,001,001
como hacer para dividir la lista en 2. una para los codigo repetidos y otro para lo no repetidos..

Answer (score 1):

Podrias usar el `group by` de linq para conocer cuales se repiten

```
var result = from item in dbcontext.NombreTabla
              group item by item.codigo into g
              select new {
                 codigo = g.Key,
                 cantidad = g.Count(),
                 items = g
              };
```

En este caso retornas todos los codigo y puedes validar usando la `cantidad` si hay repetidos

Pero si lo necesitas tambien se puede filtrar

```
var result = from item in dbcontext.NombreTabla
              group item by item.codigo into g
              where g.Count() > 1
              select new {
                 codigo = g.Key,
                 items = g
              };
```

para recorrer la lista usarias

```
foreach(var codGroup in result){
    //aqui puede acceder al codGroup.codigo, para conocer por cual esta agrupando
    foreach(var item in codGroup.items){
        //aqui puedes acceder a cada registro que tiene ese codigo
    }
}
```

[Agrupar los resultados de consultas](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/csharp/linq/group-query-results)